# Unity front end with LINQ and database entities - doable?

Tags: c#, database, linq, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple project where one can log in, browse the store's goods and add them to the cart to make an order. Using LINQ that connects to a database is required as well as the use of Entity Framework. 
WPF would be obvious but I will have some other features (displaying some premium goods real time so it can be rotated to look at) that are easier to implement in Unity. I'd like to ask anyone experienced in this stuff if it is doable to use LINQ with Unity as the front end/UI part?

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** Of course I plan to use c# all along as the tag shows. The scripts using LINQ will *not* be `MonoBehaviour` descendants.

Comment: You mean you want to use LINQ to SQL in Unity3d? I don't think it is possible (lack of `System.Data` namespace) and very dangerous to talk directly to DB from unity client.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Thanks for the help. Well it's just a simple assignment so how risky it is, it doesn't matter. What does though, is that I really can't add `using System.Data`. Does it mean that no, Unity is done for (for this project)?

Comment: As you wrote that using LINQ to talk to DB is required, than yes - it is done. Sorry.

Comment: Eh too bad. At least I found this out in the very beginning. I asked another thread on my possibilities, could you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399324/using-an-external-realtime-renderer-in-ms-blend-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Unity 2017.1, Unity has an experimental .net 4.5 support. Later on you will be able to use those I mentioned as you see fit, just bear in mind to do proper threading to avoid frozen UI.