# Using an external realtime renderer in Wpf with Blend for VS

Tags: wpf, blend, renderer

I plan to make a project where the user can view the selected items real time and rotate them around. I would like anyone experienced to tell me which sort of `renderer` apps could be used for this? The way I imagine would be that upon a click another windows appears where one can rotate the object around, fully textured and lit. 
What I could think of is [Marmoset](https://www.marmoset.co/), that has a decent online real time viewer, [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4) - if it's possible, or [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) where I can even use coded `.shader` files for my materials. Any ideas on which to use and how to achieve the effect I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Marmoset](https://www.marmoset.co/toolbag/) has a decent viewer that you can integrate to WPF seamlessly by using Mongoose http server and cefsharp (webgl enabled).